# Getting syntax error exception for "expr"

Tags: unix

My code is below

```
while read -r line do;
LineNum=`grep -n "Deep" Formula.xml | cut -d: -f 1`
TOTAL=`expr $LineNum + 9`
echo $LineNum
echo $TOTAL
done < file.txt
```

While executing the code i am getting below exception

```
expr: syntax error
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in this code?

Comment: Most probably to do with grep -n "Deep" Formula.xml | cut -d: -f 1 not returning anything.

Comment: No i am printing the variable for the command grep -n "Deep" Formula.xml | cut -d: -f 1 and it is giving the expected output. But the expr is not happening. Like the line number it is printing 38907 45607 etc etc. But when i wm trying to increment the line number by +9 using expr i am getting expr: syntax error exception

Comment: Can you post an extract from the Formula.xml file?

Comment: cross-posted on U&L https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/460009/deep-mukherjee?tab=questions